# Nodejs Mongoose find query has slow performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having an issue when performing find queries in nodejs with mongoose. While using mongo shell client, for the same query, i get a response in **2-10ms**. But when i run that same query with Mongoose i get a response in **400-550ms**. I've tried the mongodb driver also, but got same results.

First of all. Laptop specs are as follows: 2 CPU's and 4GB DDR3 RAM. I'm not sure what i am missing here.

```
mongoose.connect(config.database, function (err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);

    console.log('Connected');

    var startTime = Date.now();
    UserModel.find().lean().exec()
             .then(function (docs) {
                 console.log('Found ' + docs.length + ' documents');
                 console.log('Finished after ' + (Date.now() - startTime) + 'ms')
                 mongoose.connection.close();
             })
             .catch(function (err) {
                 console.err(err)
             });
});
```

**Result:**

```
Connected
Found 2317 documents
Finished after 456ms
```

**Shell:**

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 2317,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 9,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 2317,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 2317,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
```

**Update**

When limited to 100 on both, i get the following results:

**Shell:** 0ms
  **Nodejs:** ~70ms

**Update**
This is an example of the document structure. I have not added it before since it is not complex.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56e6cfda713e98cc1191cae0"),
    "email" : "doppelganger113@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$10$egjew7mBQtKMgVbK6uXV5uD1hO8yQZ1tU5nztmVZQ4nfhLovOKN2q",
    "firstName" : "Marko",
    "lastName" : "Kovacevicc",
    "index" : 20100140,
    "gender" : "Male",
    "role" : "SuperAdmin",
    "isActive" : true,
    "__v" : 0,
    "avatar" : {
        "small" : "http://localhost:3000/uploads/avatar/3a8ed7bb-4f60-4f69-b8fc-372d1db9b044.png",
        "medium" : "http://localhost:3000/uploads/avatar/246c6067-403d-4e47-9e65-828cfab66d84.png",
        "source" : "http://localhost:3000/uploads/avatar/01dbb51c-c957-4f67-ba36-9e8cc227168c.png"
    },
    "birthDate" : ISODate("1991-11-28T23:00:00Z")
}
```

Will test this on a server instead locally just to check if it's to the laptop. But still, those searches appear to take a lot of time, which bugs me. I know they are not the same, but i did not expect this much of a difference.Also i accidentally added mongoose debug, it was tested with and without it.

**Update**

Shell command: `db.users.find({}).explain("executionStats")`

Comment: It's likely because in the shell it actually fetches only the first 20 or so docs from the query, but your code is getting all 2317 docs.

Comment: I've tested that also, when setting limit to 30 i get the following time:
**Shell:** 0ms
**NodeJS console** 50-60ms

Comment: Can you update your question to include the exact command you're running in the shell?

Comment: Updated `db.users.find({}).explain("executionStats")`

Comment: Thanks. That command isn't actually retrieving any docs though, so of course it's fast.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the usage, but i was led to believe that it returns all documents. It says `"nReturned" : 2317`, and when i assign it to a variable `var docs = db.users.find({})` i can see that it contains 2317 documents . Am i missing something?

Comment: In your code example, `docs` is just a cursor that lets you retrieve the docs, not the actual docs themselves. To actually retrieve all the docs, you'd need to do `db.users.find({}).toArray()`.

Comment: I was to much relying on explain() , that i forgot this. Although i remember testing with this at some point, guess i was expecting a faster query that got me entangled with this. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: @JohnnyHK what is the alternative command for `.explain("executionStats")` in mongoose?